# Zoom lens for 1300D canon

Tags: lens

I have a budget of $100 but I can only find Ef lens in that price for SLR camera. Can anyone suggest a better zoom lens .I already have 18-55mm EF-s lens!

Comment: Spend more money. On the assumption that the EF lens is the 75-300, you *can* use that on an EF-S camera, but you'll be disappointed with the results.

Comment: The cheapest lens in Canon's lineup right now, which isn't even a zoom lens, is the EF 50mm f/1.8 STM, at $126 (that's direct from Canon - Amazon has at least one listing at $118), so I'm afraid $100 isn't going to get you far. You might be able to find something from some of the low-budget third parties like Yongnou or something, though. Good lenses are not cheap.

Comment: You could get one of the older Tamron 70-300 tele/macros for that, new. First lens I bought after the kit lens. Still use it. No VR, pretty slow, a bit soft at the long end, but aberration is very acceptable.

Comment: Better in what way ?

Comment: As you can see by the answers below - you do have options, especially when you get into used gear territory. However, asking for a "better" lens is like asking for a "better" car. No one can answer. What type of photography is important to you? Why is your current gear inadequate? Why the $100 limit? Is it worth it to spend less now or save up and buy later?

Answer (score 2):

Any EF or EF-S mount lens will fit on your Canon EOS 1300D. The only EOS lenses that won't fit are the EF-M lenses made for the mirrorless EOS M cameras.

In addition to Canon, there are several third party lens makers that produce lenses in the EF/EF-S mounts: Sigma, Tamron, Yongnuo, Samyang (also marketed as Rokinon and sometimes marketed under other various names such as Bower/ Walimex/ Falcon/ Albinar/ Opteka/ Quantaray/ Bell & Howell/ whatever else they're calling it this week), etc.

You should be wary that some older third party lenses made for the EOS mount may not work on newer EOS bodies due to the way the electronic communication between camera and lens is reverse engineered by the third party lens makers. Sometimes the third party lens makers will release firmware updates to make fairly recent lens models compatible with newer camera models. Unless they are one of the newer lenses from Sigma or Tamron that can be updated by the end user via a USB dock, getting the firmware updated means shipping the lens to a service center and possibly paying a small charge.

Depending on what country you are in, you might have a few options on the used lens market. If you are in the United States, companies such as KEH have a number of lenses in the [Canon EF and EF-S mounts listed](https://www.keh.com/shop/lenses/canon-digital--canon-eos--canon-ef--canon-ef-s.html?dir=asc&limit=100&multi=true&order=price&price=0-200) for less than $100. Some are listed "As Is" which means they don't work and would only be good as a 'parts' lens. "Ugly" grade probably isn't very usable, either. But anything from "BGN" (bargain) grade, which doesn't look the best but works as intended, up through "EX" (excellent), "EX+" (excellent plus), and "LN-" (almost like new) should perform as expected.

Beyond the few large retailers that have extensive used lens departments, such as B&H, Amazon, and Adorama, there is always eBay. Just be sure to read item descriptions carefully and follow eBay's general buying guidelines to protect yourself from fraud.

It should not be too difficult to find a used EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 in one of several versions or an EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 for under $100. There are plenty of them out there. I'd advise you to go for one of the 55-250mm over the 75-300mm. The EF-S 55-250mm lenses, which can only be used on APS-C "crop" bodies such as your EOS 1300D, give image quality on par with the more expensive EF 70-300mm series that can also be used on full frame cameras as well as crop bodies.

Answer (score 1):

For that budget, getting a "better" zoom lens is not really going to happen. If you want better than a used EF 75-300 III or EF-S 55-250 IS (non-STM), you have to save up and spend more money. It's just that simple.

There's nothing intrinsic about an EF lens that makes it bad/unusable on a crop body. It's the other way around where you have to be careful (you can't use EF-S lenses on full frame bodies, like the 6D).

I will add two notes.  The 75-300 III is a cheap and limited lens, but it will not turn all your images butt-ugly just because you use it.  You need to learn how to work around its weaknesses, but stopped down into the f/8-f/11 range, it can be sharp, even at 300mm. And it's extraordinarily good at being cheap, which is apparently the most important feature of a lens for you.

My second note, is that if you only have $100 budget for a new lens, you may want to rethink your dSLR ownership. dSLR gear is expensive. $100 is a laughably small amount of money in comparison with the prices the manufacturers set on their camera bodies, lenses, and accessories. It may be a lot of money to you, but it isn't to them. And the versatility and power of a dSLR system comes from owning many parts of that system. You may be better served with a cheaper, more convenient fixed-lens camera that can delivery better image quality than you can get with $100 lenses on a dSLR, as well as offering you full exposure control and RAW.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty much you cannot, not with that budget.